# JScrollPane doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, preferredsize

My JScrollPane is around JTextArea:

```
    ...
    errorText = new JTextArea();
    errorText.setLineWrap(true);
    errorText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    errorText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorText);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Info Area"));
    ...
```

and code, that adds text to errorText:

```
public void setText(String mes) {
    e140TEST2.errorText.append(lineNum + ".   " + mes + "\n");
    lineNum++;
}
```

after adding some num of lines (when text have more height, than JTextArea), JScrollPane doesn't work (text isn't scrooling). What it can be??

Comment: scrollpane scrolling the content not the text and it requires a view port to apply the visible area.

Comment: If you still need to set the size of the text area in pixels, my answer might be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> errorText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

Don't hardcode the preferred size of the text area (or any component). The preferred size changes as you add/remove text.

Instead create your text area like:

```
textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

to provide an initial size.

Comment: Nice answer, I'm late with response

Comment: Although you're answer is correct, I think you're making the very same mistake you pointed out IMHO: aren't you hardcoding dimensions too, just using different units (rows and cols)? And what if the text area's size must be set in pixels because of, say, graphic design constraints? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @hqcasanova, can't believe you down voted. This is the proper approach. All this does is "suggest" to the text area some values on which to base the preferred size. The text area will then take into account the Font that is used (which is probably different for every LAF). Many Swing components have this concept. With a text field you can also specify the number of columns. With a JList you specify the number of visible rows. If you truly need a size in pixels, then you override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return your dimension.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did downvote your response since you just mentioned in passing why the OP should not hardcode those dimensions. Naturally, I agree that's not the ideal solution. Unfortunately, the code you may be handed from another developer is not always ideal. Perhaps that's the situation the OP finds himself in. Also, I'm sure you realise we're here to learn and *teach*, not *lecture*. So, instead of *“Don't hardcode [...]”*, I'd rather say *”You should avoid hardcoding”* and explain why. Of course, I'm happy to upvote if you edit your answer along those lines.

Comment: @hqcasanova, down voting is done when the answer is wrong or misleading. There is nothing wrong or misleading about my answer. We are under no obligation to write a tutorial explaining the answer. People up vote when then like the answer. If my answer doesn't meet your criteria for an up vote, that's fine but don't impose your standards on other. Notice the first comment was `nice answer`!

Comment: Thanks @camickr. I refer to my very first comment: *"Although you're answer is correct"*. Concerning your comment: *"We are under no obligation to write a tutorial"*. Really? I edited my answer to explain why the OP shouldn't use that solution all the time and it took me just 3 lines. That's not what I'd call a tutorial. If you don't want to edit your answer, that's fine with me. I'm not imposing anything. But votes are a measure of entry's quality and, to me, yours is incomplete as it stands. That is not to say that others like alex2410 will agree with me.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the ideal solution, you can still set a **preferred size in pixels** and retain scrolling capabilities if you use a [**JTextPane**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instance instead of a JTextArea one. Plus, JTextPane automatically wraps lines and does so at word boundaries (which is what you seem to be after). Try the following SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class PaneWithScroll {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JTextPane errorText = new JTextPane();
        //errorText.setLineWrap(true);       
        //errorText.setWrapStyleWord(true);         
        errorText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (errorText);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy 
                          (ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        scrollPane.setBorder (BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Info Area"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add (scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

I should add that this may serve as a quick patch. However, best practices dictate that you should always try to decouple potentially platform-dependent specifications from your GUI design. In this case, absolute dimensions.

Hope that helps!

Comment: frame.pack() what is it?

Comment: @AndrewEvt See what happens if you taking it out. Whenever you set preferred sizes on the components of a JFrame, is good practice to let Java determine what the minimum size of that JFrame should be so that all its components show. That's what [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) does. Unless, that is, you want the frame to be bigger than the minimum size (as in a maximised window, for example). [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) might help you. Happy coding!

Comment: No you should NOT use the `setPreferredSize()` method. Don't take my word for this, search around the forum (especially commments from kleopatra - a SwingX designer) for other peoples views.  JTextArea supports word wrapping and is more efficient than a JTextPane. You should only use a JTextPane if you actually need the features it supports like different fonts, colors etc. By the way it is not a proper SSCCE because all Swing components should be created on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr Again, sometimes you have to set aside purisms and do a quick and dirty patch. That's different from saying you can always use the same patch, which I'm not. Also, JtextArea is more efficient than a JtextPane? I beg to differ. Granted the OP may never need any styling capabilities but that does not go in detriment of the efficiency of the solution. It even makes it more flexible. Finally, since when did “Correct” in SSCCE stand for “perfection”? Perfection may compromise simplicity. In this particular case, the minimal thread safety that Swing offers is more than enough. Thanks again.

Comment: Many of us have been answering questions for years. We see the same questions/problems appear on a daily basis. Many of these problems are because people copy old code found on forums. Take a look at all the [top swing users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers). Because of this we promote the proper practices to minimize potential future problems.

Comment: `set aside purisms and do a quick and dirty patch` - There is absolutely no reason to do that with this question. And if you ever do this, then you should be aware of the problems this will cause. The OP is obviously a beginner if they have to ask this question and as such they should be given the proper solution, not a hack. Why would you ever pick a random height for the text area. This might mean you display 3 1/2 line of text instead of 3 or 4. This makes you app look completely unprofessional and is unnecessary when there is such a simple solution by using the API.

Comment: @camickr Please, read my answer more carefully. *"then you should be aware of the problems this will cause"*. Hence, my edit: *"However, best practices dictate"*. Also, you say: *"proper solution, not a hack"*. This is clearly not a hack. I've just used documented classes and methods. As always, tell me where's the hack and I'll be happy to edit. *"Random height"*. It might be random to you but not for the OP in the context of his design, regardless of how "noobish" he is. *"app look completely unprofessional"*. Hey this is an example, not a roadmap for the next word processor.

Comment: Now, this discussion is no longer adding any more value to the answers. Thus, I shall not make any more comments.

Comment: `But votes are a measure of entry's quality and, to me, yours is incomplete as it stands.` Your "edit" was made a day later after this discussion started, so I could say the same of your original answer. But unlike you I didn't down vote it because the basic answer was reasonable (if not advisable).

Comment: By the way your solution is an anomaly. In other components, like JTextArea, JTable, JPanel, once you hard code a preferred size you break scrolling. So if the OP tries to use this solution and then apply it to other components it won't work and the OP will be back on the forum asking why. My answer tried to address this by suggesting not to hardcode the size and instead use properties of the component to let the component determine its size.